# How can I make my website appear 100% even if I have the scaling set to 125% in Windows?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, scaling

How can I make my website appear 100% even if I have the scaling set to 125% in Windows?

The most important thing is the website font size. Maybe I can use other units than "px"?

Appreciate all the tips I can get!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Adjusting viewport width with JS**

document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale='+(1/window.devicePixelRatio));

**2. Tweaking your stylesheet to make breakpoints reflect real device width**

```
@media (min-width: 1200px), (min-width: 960px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25) {
  /* Add Styles Here */
}
```

**3 Detecting the specific pixel ratio and then zooming everything out**

```
@media (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25) {
  * {
    zoom: 0.8;
  }
}
```